# How to write optimized constructor in a class >

Tags: c++, class

I wrote writing an email class, but I am not sure if this is the best way to write this... here's the code for it...

```
class email
{
    string value;
    string domain;
    string com;
    string username;
    string encrypted;
    bool state ;
public:
    email(const string& val)
        :value{ val}, state{false},com(),domain(),username(),encrypted()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (value[i] == '@')
            {
                username = value.substr(0, i);
                for (int j = i; j < value.size(); ++j)
                {
                    if (value[j] == '.')
                    {
                        domain = value.substr(i, j);
                        com = value.substr(j+1, value.size()-1);
                        state = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (state)
        {
            for (auto letter : value)
            {
                if (letter == ';' || letter == '\'' || letter == '[' || letter == ']')
                {
                    state = false;
                    
                }
            }

        } else throw "invalid string";
        if (state)
        {
            encrypted = username;
            for (int i = 0; i < username.size() / 2; ++i)
            {
                swap(encrypted[i], encrypted[encrypted.size() - 1 - i]);
                encrypted[i] = static_cast<char>(static_cast<int>(encrypted[i]) + 3);
                
            }
        }else throw "invalid charecters";
    }
    const string& get_domain() { return domain; }
    const string& get_username() { return username; }
    const string& get_com() { return com; }
    const string& get_enc() { return encrypted; }
    const  bool good () const { return state; }
};
```

It's not completed yet, this is just a quick sketch from what I can remember because I don't have the actual code right now, my question is should I make another class to support the email class.. or is this the right way? I wrote a **lot of code inside the constructor**, that's what I am worried about.

Comment: All these initializers `com(),domain(),username(),encrypted()` don't do anything useful.

Comment: The member initializer list lists the members in the wrong order and the getter methods should be `const`.

Comment: Instead of looping over the strings I would use `std::string::find` and `std::any_of`.

Comment: Post [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you need a detailed review. As for your question "should I make another clas" - no you should not. Instead you should clean your code, move the username, domain etc. extraction code to separate functions, don't throw strings, move private data to the bottom of your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break the for loops, if you have done your stuff.
First for: after you found '@' you do not have to loop to the end
Third for: after you found an error, you could throw immediatelly